# Using Web Push API with cordova phonegap-plugin-push and FCM

Tags: firebase, cordova, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, phonegap-plugin-push

We've a cordova app that uses push notifications which works fine on android and iOS. I now thought I'd like to test if I also get the [Web Push API](https://www.w3.org/TR/push-api/) to work on the browser platform / as PWA.

However, I didn't manage to find any guidance how to do this.

Nearly all examples I found that have the browser platform included use the example from https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md#pushnotificationinitoptions

```
const push = PushNotification.init({
  browser: {
    pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
  }
});
```

However, the domain `push.api.phonegap.com` seems to be non-existent by now.

The [Firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client) I found doesn't explain how to use FCM with the push plugin that already does most of the stuff described there (I would expect).

I found [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169181/push-notifications-with-fcm-on-devextreme-phonegap) that uses `pushServiceURL: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'` but the question already states that *"First of all, I don't know if the pushServiceURL is correct. Is this the URL to use if I'd like to send some notifications from FCM?"*

And I understand https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref that this URL is the server-side API.

So, did anyone manage to use the Web Push API with the phonegap-plugin-push? With FCM or with andouter service?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm using phonegap-push-plugin on an Ionic app and I cannot figure out how to send notification to the browser.

Comment: Not yet, sorry.